# Zeitkonflikt bei Kausalsatz

Tags: grammar, grammatical-case

> Laura hat die ganze Nacht getanzt, sodass/weswegen ihr die Füße am Morgen wehtun.

Warum steht *wehtun* im Präsens und nicht in Präteritum?

Comment: Die Frage wäre die selbe, wenn der Satz lediglich „Laura tun am Morgen die Füße weh“ lautete. Sie lässt sich ohne Kontext nicht beantworten. Ich kann mir vorstellen, dass Dich die Zeitangabe im Zusammenhang mit dem Präsenz verwirrt. Das ist aber nicht unüblich, wenn es sich um eine Erzählung handelt, für die das Präsenz und nicht das Präteritum verwandt wird, um sie direkter wirken zu lassen.

Answer (score 3):

Die Zeitformen können im Deutschen relativ frei gewählt werden. Das Präsens im Nebensatz kann mehreres bedeuten:

- Es findet tatsächlich gerade statt.
- Es ist generell / im Allgemeinen so.
- Es wird in der Zukunft stattfinden. (Der Redezeitpunkt ist vielleicht gerade das Zubettgehen von Laura.)

Die einzige Bedingung, die auch umgangssprachlich an die Zeitformen gestellt wird, ist die relative Konsistenz: Wenn Prozess A vor Prozess B stattfindet, kann für Prozess A keine zukünftigere Zeitform als für Prozess B gewählt werden.

Wenn der Nebensatz im Präteritum stünde

> Laura hat die ganze Nacht getanzt, sodass ihr die Füße am Morgen *wehtaten*.

so stellt es das einen Grenzfall dar. Präteritum ist eigentlich eine Vergangenheitszeitform, während Perfekt eine Gegenwartszeitform ist. Heutzutage verdrängt das Perfekt aber das Präteritum als Vergangenheitszeitform, insbesondere in der Umgangssprache.

Diese Variante würde also manche Menschen verwirren, für andere wäre sie OK.

Comment: Ich habe gestern etwas zum Thema gelesen und möchte das hier gern ergänzen: http://www.belleslettres.eu/artikel/prateritum-imperfekt-perfekt.php
Dort steht zu literarischem Deutsch: »Am Morgen rasierte er sich, wie es Männer eben taten.
Falsch wäre das Präsens (... wie es Männer eben tun). Das Prä­sens existiert in einem Roman nicht, denn grundsätzlich kennt die Erzählstimme eines Romans nur Präteritum und Plusquam­perfekt. Präsens und Perfekt kommen nur in wörtlicher Rede der Figuren vor […]«
Wenn es also lit. Deutsch ist, müsste es wohl eher »hatte getanzt« und »wehtaten« heißen.

Comment: @AlexE, das ist ein guter Hinweis, aber man muss Daniel Scholten auch nicht in allem folgen.

Comment: @AlexE Insbesondere in der Literatur gilt auch die künstlerische Freiheit. Es ist ein übliches Stilmittel, im Präsens zu reden, um den Erzähler in eine deutliche Nähe zu den handelnden Figuren und der Handlung selbst zu stellen.

Comment: @AlexE: Wenn man das Konstrukt außerhalb von Romanen betrachtet, dann bedeutet "Am Morgen rasierte er sich, wie es Männer eben tun" dass Männer sich heutzutage immer noch rasieren, während "Am Morgen rasierte er sich, wie es Männer eben taten" auch dann gälte, wenn die Männer sich heute nicht mehr rasierten. Ich schätze, die zweite Form ist im Roman angesagt, weil der Roman ja keine Aussage über die heutige reale Welt, sondern nur über die Romanwelt machen soll (über die dort eben in der Vergangenheitsform geschrieben wird).

Comment: @celtschk Vielleicht möchte der Autor aber eben doch eine Aussage über die reale Welt machen oder Realität und Fiktion verschwimmen lassen. (Metafiktion)

Comment: @celtschk Laut Meinung des Autors ist das Präteritum in Romanen einfach nur die Erzählform, keine Vergangenheit. Er schreibt dazu: »Das Prä­te­ri­tum als Erzählzeit des Romans berich­tet nicht von Ver­gan­ge­nem, son­dern schil­dert die er­zähl­te Zeit als Gegen­wart und Wirk­lich­keit der Ge­schich­te.« und »Daß es so und nicht um­ge­kehrt ist, wird bei Roma­nen deut­lich, die in der Zu­kunft spie­len. Auch sie wer­den im Prä­te­ri­tum er­zählt.« (Zweiter Absatz in Per­fekt und Prä­te­ri­tum in li­te­ra­rischem Deutsch)

Ob alles in dem Artikel stimmt, kann ich natürlich nicht beurteilen.

Comment: @celtschk Wenn man aber annimmt, dass das Präsens in Romanen erlaubt ist, stimme ich dir voll zu. Leider bin ich kein Sprachwissenschaftler ;)

Answer (score 2):

Die Zeitform von 'wehtun' ist Präsens, da zum Zeitpunkt dieser Aussage tatsächlich Morgen ist. Davon gehe ich aus, da 'getanzt' im Perfekt steht, die Nacht also vorbei ist. Wenn der Morgen noch nicht erreicht ist, müsste 'wehtun' im Futur stehen.

> Laura hat die ganze Nacht getanzt, sodass/weswegen ihr die Füße am Morgen(jetzt) wehtun.

Die Nacht / das Tanzen ist vorbei, jetzt ist Morgen.

> Laura hat die ganze Nacht getanzt, sodass/weswegen ihr die Füße am Morgen wehtun werden.

Die Nacht / das Tanzen ist vorbei, aber es ist noch nicht Morgen.

Answer (score 1):

@Sam good but.

I know why mina is asking she has a point. The sentence does not make much sense. Even though grammatically you could write it this way.

> Laura hatte die ganze Nacht, so dass ihr die Füße am (nächsten) Morgen
>   wehtaten.

--> This is more precise and less akward.

> Laura tantzte die ganze Nacht, so dass ihr die Füße **heute** Morgen
>   wehtun.

--> And she was still dancing in the Morning?

> Laura tanzte die ganze Nacht, so dass ihr die Füße am Morgen wehtun.

--> This is passive voice 3rd person

> Ich tanzte die ganze Nacht, so dass mir jetzt die Füße wehtun.

--> In first person singular you'd not necessarily say am morgen when it is morgen when you are talking about it

> Ich hatte die ganze Nacht (durch)getanzt, so dass mir am (folgenden)
>   Morgen die Füße wehtaten.

--> This makes more sense since you are reporting about two past events in the future.

Comment: Wie kann man zwischen bisher und bislang vergleichen .
  Sind sie gleich ?